# Suppose foo.c contains the global definition int secret = 4;

Tags: c, global-variables

I was given this question on one of my reviews for a final exam. I'm a little stumped on it. ***(This is being compiled in PuTTy in a Linux environment)***

> > ***Question:*** Suppose `foo.c` contains the global definition `int secret = 4;`, and `bar.c` contains the global definition `char secret[16];`
> >     What will happen when `foo.c` and `bar.c` are linked together? How much memory will be reserved for `secret`?

*My Attempt:* I think that since they are both global definitions of the same name that they are both **strong** variables and will not compile (i.e. a linker error) because you can not have multiple strong variables.. Where I am confused is how much memory will actually be reserved for `secret`. Perhaps it's trivial, would it be (16 bytes since char is 1 byte) + 4 bytes for the integer resulting in a total 20 bytes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a bad exam question to me, since this isn't something anyone should ever do.  Basically you have conflicting global definitions of the same name.  I personally would want an error for this, but in practice, I think the initialized definition will take precedence, resulting in a size of 4 (assuming 4-byte integers).

Comment: Ahh. Is there any references you can send me to for sources for your answer? I think you are correct.

Comment: _`ld: warning: tentative definition of '_secret' with size 16 from '...' is being replaced by real definition of smaller size 4 from '...'`_

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the integer declaration hold precedence over the char array declaration (since they both have the same name) ? Also would it be correct to say that since the integer declaration takes precedence it try to allocate 4 bytes for the 16 byte character array and tries to fit the 16 byte character array into a 4 byte space? Or am I way off the mark there

Comment: The reason the integer definition overrides the char definition is because of the initializer.  That makes it a definition, while the uninitialized declaration is a "common" reference.  In Unix, "common" references are handled quite loosely.  If there are several common references, but no definition, then the largest reference takes precedence and is allocated.  If there is a definition, then the definition takes precedence and all common references resolve to it.

Comment: Since OP has not specified a compiler/platform, the result is either indeterminable or an expected linker error.  I would prefer settings such that the link fails as it is certainly a bug.

Comment: Updated OP - so it is known the compiler/platform being used. i.e: ***(This is being compiled in PuTTy in a Linux environment)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are conflicting definitions so it won't link so no memory is reserved for secret, or anything else.